# ASP.Net circular reference situation

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code and everytime i try to compile, I get the error "/Website/InsightLogo.ascx has a circular reference!" I am assigned to fix up somebody els' code, so please excuse any odd mistakes

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="InsightLogo.ascx.vb" Inherits="eDox.InsightLogo" %>
<%@ Register Src="InsightLogo.ascx" TagName="InsightLogo" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
&nbsp;<img src="Images/InsightLogo.bmp" alt="Company Logo"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your control is trying to register itself.

You should remove the following line :

```
<%@ Register Src="InsightLogo.ascx" TagName="InsightLogo" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
```

Comment: Where should I rather paste that line instead? Since its not my code, im unsure what would happen if i am to simply remove the line.

Comment: @ReidGarwin the line is useless and prevents compilation. Please post the whole markup code of your user control, so we can see if it is meant to be of some use

Comment: You should try to find out what is the essence of that line, then figure out how to replace it without breaking any functionality. May be there is an alternative...

Comment: The alternative might be to simply recode the entire project lol.